# Вывести ключ массива с определенной вероятностью

Tags: php

Задание заключалось в следующем
Дан массив:
array
(
'a' => 1/3,
'b' => 1/6,
'c' => 1/2
);
Необходимо написать класс или функцию, 
реализующую следующие требования:
на вход подается массив указанного формата,
на выход обязательно возвращается один ключ переданного массива,
при многократном вызове функции ключи массива должны возвращаться с пропорциями, 
указанными в значениях.
Пример:
На вход подается массив 
a=>1/8, b=>1/2, при запуске функции большое количество раз, в 20% 
случаев должен вернуться ключ a, в остальных –b

```
$arr = array('a' => 1/3,'b' => 1/6,'c' => 1/2);


class Foo
{
    private static $math = array();
    private static $iter = 0;


    public static function process($arr)
    {
        $summ = 0;
        foreach($arr as $k=>$d)
        {
            $summ+=$d;
        }

        self::$math = array();

        foreach($arr as $k=>$d)
        {
            $math[$k] = round((100 * $d) / $summ);
        }

        $id = mt_rand(0,100);

        asort($math);

        foreach($math as $key =>$value)
        {


        }

    }
}




for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
    echo "<br>";
    echo Foo::process($arr);
}
```

Есть массив $math в которм пропорции которые были в входящем массиве переведены проценты:

```
Array ( [a] => 33 [b] => 17 [c] => 50 )
```

Суть в том что я не могу никак додуматься как сделать проверку и вернуть ключ, в завасимости от его вероятности

Comment: сортируем по значению, генерируем случайное число от 0 до 100 и выводим ключ, который этому числу соответствует. Например, выпало "51", смотрим первый ключ - от 0 до 17 - не попало, смотрим второй ключ - от 17 до 50 - не попало, смотрим следующий ключ - от 50 до 100 - попало, выводим его

Comment: спасибо, а как проверить в какой интервал попало рандомное значение?

Comment: не понял вопроса, на каждом шаге вы же знаете текущий ключ, а значит знаете его значение + на каждом шаге у вас будет текущая вероятность, по которой будете границы теукщего ключа определять

Comment: суть в том что мне нужно использовать foreach, т.к ключейи может быть бесконечно много, 
т.е код такой 

`$id = mt_rand(0,100);
  
  asort($math);
  
  foreach($math as $key =>$value)
  {
   if(...)
    return $key;
  }`

Comment: т.е вопрос в том что мне написать в условии?

Comment: В описании нет вопроса. Что вы сами сделали? В чем проблема? Вам тут не фриланс.

Comment: изменил тело вопроса на более подробную версию

Comment: перед циклом делаете `$total = 0`, в цикле делаете `total += $value; if ($total > $id) { return $key; }`. На большом количестве итераций (около 2000) уже хорошо заметно совпадение ожидаемых вероятностей

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё очень просто. Создайте массив ключей `$key_percent` на 100 элементов, положите туда каждого из ключей согласно процентам в Вашем массиве (33 ключа "a", 17 ключей "b" и 50 ключей "с", можно подряд) и делайте вызов   `$key=$key_percent[mt_rand(0,99)]`.

Comment: А если элементов передали 200, или если вероятности `1/200, 2/200, 197/200` ?

Comment: @Sergiks Если вероятности заданы в двухсотых долях, то массив на 200 элементов и `mt_rand(0,199)`.

Comment: для двух вероятностей: `1/1e6, 999999/1e6` предлагаете массив на миллион значений пилить?

Comment: @Sergiks в рамках авторской постановки вопроса (**многократный вызов функции**, **есть массив math**) такой вариант получше. Но превращать решение конкретной (видимо, учебной) задачи в панацею на все случаи жизни я бы не стал.

Comment: Кстати, даже для оценочного тестирования в Вашем варианте надо перебрать хотя бы десяток миллионов значений.

Comment: с т.з. теории вероятностей может случиться и так, что за 10 млн вызовов ни разу не выскочет первый вариант, и так, что первый выскочет хоть все 10 млн. раз – если случайность действительно случайна.

Comment: Вы правы. С вероятностью 4.5*10^(-5), Хотя доверительная вероятность для тестов обычно 95%

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, значения в массиве это доли вероятности. В сумме должны составить 1 (ну или около того).

Я набросал функцию, выдающую ключ массива с заданной вероятностью. И тестовый вывод, по которому можно оценить результат.
Я умножаю вероятность на 100 чтобы сравнивать с целым случайным числом, но в принципе там можно использовать произвольное большое целое.

```
<?php

$arr = array('a' => 1/3,'b' => 1/6,'c' => 1/2);

function probe($arr)
{
    $rand = mt_rand(1, 100);
    $x = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $x += $v * 100;
        if ($rand <= $x) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $k;
}

$counters = array_fill_keys(array_keys($arr), 0);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100000; ++$i) {
    $x = probe($arr);
    $counters[$x]++;
}
var_export($counters);
```

**P.S.** Сначала написал ответ, потом уже почитал комментарии к вопросу и увидел, что ВОРОН эту схему в точности обрисовал. Очевидно решение довольно очевидное. :)

Comment: [те же](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470538/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e/470550?noredirect=1#comment526038_470550) недостатки

Answer (score 0):

Для более общего случая, когда вероятности не приведены в целые проценты:

1. найти наибольший общий делитель для переданных вероятностей, возможно, с некоторым округлением;
2. сложить все числители после приведения к общему знаменателю (НОД) и привести эту сумму к целому числу `M`;
3. получить `mt_rand(0,M)` случайное целое число `R` из диапазона от 0 до этой суммы;
4. от `S = 0`, прибавляя по очереди каждый из числителей, сравнивать `R` с текущим значением `S` – как только сравнение с `>` сменится на `<=` –  найден выпавший вариант.